# Black Scholes SDE

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

[image]

This is only part of the solution I got stuck on. I don't quite understand how can the instructor got from $\rm{d} (\log S_t) = \frac{dS_t}{S_t}$.

Thank you.

[image]

And also where did the negative sign coming from in the very last formula ? Shouldn't it be plus sign ? Thank you.

Comment: Your second question: $\frac{\partial}{\partial{S_t}}{\frac{1}{S_t}}=-\frac{1}{S_t^2}$. Furthermore, is the second picture your own writing? Because there are some inaccuracies...

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, the picture isn't my own writing is my lecture notes, would you mind point out the inaccuracies please, thank you.

Comment: The _In other words_ line has some misplaced dollar signs.
    What is used in the last line is commonly known as It\^o's Lemma, not _It formula_.
    In the last line, the apostrophes can be dropped, as the subscripts in $g_t$, $g_s$ and $g_{ss}$ already denote derivatives. **Edit** Okay if someone could tell me how to properly write $\mathrm{It\hat{o}'s\ Lemma}$ that'd be nice, cause it's really pissing me off.

Comment: @Did, yes that works in actual LaTeX, but not on this site: \^o and \^{o}

Comment: Right. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Did and Eric S. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember what the derivative of a logarithm is: $$\frac{d}{dS_t}\log S_t = \frac{1}{S_t}$$

EDIT: As Eric S. points out, the second derivative of a logarithm is $$\frac{d^2}{dS_t^2}\log S_t=\frac{d}{dS_t}\frac{1}{S_t}=\frac{-1}{S_t^2}$$